# how to get date format from date object?

Tags: python, django

insert function:

```
 def done(self, request, form_list):
    model_form, field_form = form_list
    query = SortedDict()
    for field_name in field_form.fields:
        app, model, field = field_name.split('__')
        name = '%s__%s' % (model, field)
        value = field_form.cleaned_data[field_name]
        #print value
        if value or value == 0:
            query[name] = value
            print value

    query['data_model_name'] = [model.split('__')[1] for model in field_form.model_list]
    Model_name.objects.create(name=model_form.cleaned_data['report_name'],query=query)
    messages.success(request, "The report has been created successfully")
    return redirect('....')
```

i am getting this type input data form db

input data :

```
{'Locator__creation_date':
 {'start': datetime.date(2013, 11, 8), 'end': datetime.date(2013, 11, 28)}
}
```

how to got this type output

```
{'Locator__creation_date':
{'start':  "start": "2013-09-02", "end": "2013-10-31"}
}
```

i using django framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cast a `datetime` object to a string, use `datetime.strftime()`. There is a defined syntax of format strings, see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). In this case, you want

```
myDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: i have update my code with mydate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
now i am getting "TypeError: expected string or buffer"